# How to clean up a mesh in order to export a freestyle vector for a 3D engraved lamp?

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to create meshes for a 3D illusion lamp that is made through laser engraving acrylic. Like the one on the below picture.

[image]

As I'm new to 3D modelling and I mostly do architecture stuff or furniture, I really struggle with organic shapes, which are most of the requests that I get now. As an example, I downloaded [this model](https://free3d.com/es/modelo-3d/american-quarter-horse-walking-v1--526945.html) and as you can see below, the mesh is way too dense for my purpose.
[image]

I tried to decimate the mesh but the result I get is not what I'm after as it ends up being triangles rather than a tidy mesh like the shark above.

[image]

Is there a way to get a similar result cleaning up the mesh? Or is the only way modelling it from the scratch (in which case I would have to give up as I can't model such a complex shape).

All the freestyle  vector export I can handle. It's the mesh that's my problem. I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Object Data Properties tab, and under *Remesh*, set the mode to Quad and click *Quadriflow Remesh*

[image: Quad1]

Set the target number of faces (I set 20,000 - eventually you will lose an undesired amount of mesh resolution, so don't go too low) and click the Ok button.

[image: Quad2]

The result (at 20,000) looks like this:

[image: Quad3]

The mesh looks even better at 10,000, but you will begin to get some artefacts if you get too low, so I suggest somewhere between 12,000 and 20,000 for your final result.

[image: Quad4]

Comment: Man, I can't thank you enough! Wish you knew how much this helps. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer the question, it matters a lot!
Thank you!

Comment: Hey no problem. I played around a bit more - 11,000 faces seems to be the lowest you can go without artefacts, although the ears begin to look bit lumpy at that level. I tried adding a decimate modifier afterwards set to "unsubdivide" level 2, which gets closer to a less dense mesh, but adds some strange connecting lines. Try for yourself, but I doubt you'll like the results.

Comment: I'll give it a try with the laser tomorrow but it's looking good! Thank you again!
Btw, cool theme ;)

Comment: Just to update, it worked amazing. I stayed up all night working on it and first thing today in the shop was making one in the laser; just awesome.
Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Hey, glad it worked for you. If I ever have questions about 3D laser engraving, I know who to ask now.